# Windows XP does not recognize any wireless networks

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

I've got a Fujitsu Siemens Computers Amilo LA1703 laptop, which I bought a few years ago. Now I decided to connect it to my router, via wireless. As I installed Windows XP on the laptop recently, the wireless stopped working. Before that, I had both Vista and Windows 7 installed, and I could connect to any wireless network in range. After I installed Windows XP, neither does Windows recognize any wireless networks, nor I know what is wrong. After trying pretty much everything I was able to do with the laptop, and still did not get it work, I wanted to ask you, users, to help me. The only message I know is that Windows says "Wireless network unavailable" when the wireless card is turned on, and when it's turned off also.

If you need any other information, feel free to ask!

Comment: Did you install the XP drivers for your notebook's wireless adapter? Did you try the latest ones from the notebook's or wireless adapter's manufacturer? Also, perhaps include what you specifically tried when you say "After trying pretty much everything I was able to do with the laptop", it will help keep us from repeating things you've already tried.

Comment: Yes, I installed the official drivers, the device is listed in the device manager, just not recognizing any networks. I tried to change the wireless encryption method, to make it open, change the wireless network type, tried to scout the networks with network stumbler, to add the network to preferred networks... everything I could find on the internet, and everything I could think off...

Comment: You have all updates installed right?

Comment: Did you install _all_ the official drivers and utilities?  Sometimes the Wireless adapters on notebooks are useless until some goofy power management application is installed.

Comment: What applications for example? Yes, all updates are installed.

Comment: When doing wireless on XP here, the manufactures wireless software sort-of conflicted with the windows "wireless zero configuration" thing. We had installed the devices software and windows could also handle the wireless by itself, once the wireless driver only was installed. So we certanly needed the driver, but had to chose one of the softwares, not both.